# Floating point variables in c++

Tags: c++, double

When i use float or double in c++ after eight digit is getting overflow, how fix it?

This is my code :

```
#include <iostream.h> 
#include <conio.h> 
void main() { 
  double x; 
  cout<<"double : "; 
  cin>>x; 
  cout<<endl<<x; 
  getch(); 
}
```

When cin = 123456789 , this is my cout : 123457e.08.

Comment: can you show some example code?

Comment: #include <iostream.h>
#include <conio.h>
void main()
{
double x;
cout<<"double : ";
cin>>x;
cout<<endl<<x;
getch();
}

Comment: when cin   123456789     , this is my cout :  123457e.08

Answer (score 5):

Use dot: double x = 2398479238749234.0

Comment: Just to elaborate on BarsMonster's answer: by omitting the decimal point, you are actually using integer literals, whose maximum value is INT_MAX (typically 2147483647). If you specify a larger number, it will overflow. Only after this will the value be implicitly cast to a double.

Answer (score 2):

If you declare a float you can type `f` at the end like this:

```
float var = 123456789.0f;
```

---

**A simple yet interesting demonstration:**

To see the importance of `f` try this code:

```
 float f1 = 1.3f;
 //test f1
 if ( f1 == 1.3f )
  std::cout<<"f1 is equal to 1.3f"<<std::endl;
 else
  std::cout<<"f1 is not equal to 1.3f"<<std::endl;

 float f2 = 1.3;
 //test f2
 if ( f2 == 1.3 )
  std::cout<<"f2 is equal to 1.3"<<std::endl;
 else
  std::cout<<"f2 is not equal to 1.3"<<std::endl;
```

Output:

> f1 is equal to 1.3f
>   f2 is not equal to 1.3

See demonstration at ideone : http://www.ideone.com/QvzEp

Comment: If you omit f meaning would not change )